# Run the powershell script from client machine

Tags: javascript, php, html, powershell, xampp

I have a requirement to run the powershell script from client machine whenever they click on the button, hosted the website using XAMPP and placed all the required files in htdocs folder,

```
<form action="site.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="submit" name="getprocess" class="btn btn-default" value="Prototype"/> 
</form> </li>

<?php

if(array_key_exists('getprocess', $_POST)) { 
  GetProcess(); 
} 

function GetProcess() { 
  echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File ".\myscript.ps1"');
  //echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html"');
}
```

But the script is running on webserver if we click the prototype button from client side, please suggest me if anything needs to modified to make the script run directly from client machine

Comment: Short answer, you can't from a web site. That would be a HUGE security hole. You could offer something to them to download and then execute but, hopefully, most people would not even consider doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a script on the client from a website. That would be a massive security hole!

Here is what you can do instead:

Use the PowerShell command "Invoke-Command" to execute the script from the server on the clients. More here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

This might help
we used exec command to execute R file as follow

```
$invoirment_vars = 'export R_LIBS="/usr/lib64/R/library"; export R_LIBS_USER="/usr/lib64/R/library"; export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/;';

$rfile = 'abc.R';
$rdir = '/var/www/domainnam.com/htdocs/rdir';
$exe_command = "cd $rdir && Rscript " . $rfile;

exec($invoirment_vars . $exe_command);
```

so you may also try to send environment variables as per your system